# gcc compiler printf execution order

Tags: c, gcc, printf

For the testing code as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int addTen(int x, int b[])
{
  b[2] =  x + b[2];
  return b[2];
}
void main(void)
{
   int a[3] = {4,5,6};
   int i = 2;
   printf("%i %i %i \n", a[i], addTen(10,a), a[i]);
}
```

Why is the output is 16, 16, 6? I know that even if the compiler processes the order from right to left like  a[i] <- addTen(10,a) <-a[i]. After calling addTen(10,a), a[i] is already 16 (not 6). So why the output is not 16, 16,16? THANKS!

Comment: Presumably because this compiler, at this phase of the moon, evaluates the arguments from right to left as you describe, so `a[i]` is 6 when it evaluates the last one, and 16 when it evaluates the second. But of course this is undefined behaviour, so there isn't an answer.

Comment: `main` needs to return `int`.

Answer (score 4):

It's ***undefined behavior***, you should read about [sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328). You're modifying `a` and simultaneously reading it in a same expression.

In addition the order of evaluating is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

There's no order defined for evaluating arguments. The compiler is free to evaluate arguments in any order, and will normally choose the most convenient order. So, you can't define any expected output.